# How to insert FOR AUTO XML result into table?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, insert

I have retrieved the values from a table using

```
select *  from tableABC 
for xml auto, elements
```

Now,  there is this exact table **tableABC** on another server into which  I need to insert these retrieved values  .

How to achieve that?

Comment: @Andomar please see edit ... I dropped the XMLSChema necessity...so now I have a XML doc without schema in need of insertion.

Comment: Is there a client here or is this inside a stored proc. Are you intending to call a stored proc on the target or just execute some sql?

Comment: @Conrad Frix No Client. Any means to achieve insertion..SP is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Test table and data

```
create table tableABC(A int, B bit, C varchar(10))
insert into tableABC values(1, 1, 'Row 1')
insert into tableABC values(2, 0, 'Row 1')
```

Get the xml

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = (select *
            from tableABC
            for xml auto, elements)
```

XML data

```
<tableABC>
  <A>1</A>
  <B>1</B>
  <C>Row 1</C>
</tableABC>
<tableABC>
  <A>2</A>
  <B>0</B>
  <C>Row 1</C>
</tableABC>
```

Insert into another tableABC

```
insert into tableABC(A, B, C)
select 
  r.value('A[1]', 'int'),
  r.value('B[1]', 'bit'),
  r.value('C[1]', 'varchar(10)')
from @xml.nodes('tableABC') t(r)
```

**Edit** Copy this entire statement to test if it works

```
use tempdb
go

create table tableABC(A int, B bit, C varchar(10))

go
insert into tableABC values(1, 1, 'Row 1')
insert into tableABC values(2, 0, 'Row 1')

declare @xml xml
set @xml = (select *
            from tableABC
            for xml auto, elements)

insert into tableABC(A, B, C)
select 
  r.value('A[1]', 'int'),
  r.value('B[1]', 'bit'),
  r.value('C[1]', 'varchar(10)')
from @xml.nodes('tableABC') t(r)

select *
from tableABC

go

drop table tableABC
```

Result is duplicated rows in tableABC

```
A           B     C
----------- ----- ----------
1           1     Row 1
2           0     Row 1
1           1     Row 1
2           0     Row 1
```

Comment: @GilliVilla - Added something for you to test. I guess you have a typo in your code.