# How can I pass xml data from one sproc to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 sprocs for an assignment, what I'm trying to do is pass the xml output from one sproc to another and put it in a variable, I know ex1.xml_sp1 is returning an int while calling it with `EXEC` and obviously when trying to select this it returns null because `@x` is xml data type.

What I want to do is retrieve and store the xml data from sproc 1 in to `@x` in sproc 2.

Is there any way to do this?

sproc 1:

```
ALTER PROC [ex1].[xml_sp1]
@careteamid int
as

select CareTeams.CareTeamID, Doctors.DoctorID, Doctors.DoctorName,
   CareTeamDoctors.DateJoined, CareTeamDoctors.CurrentMember
from dbo.CareTeamTbl as CareTeams
inner join dbo.CareTeamDoctorTbl as CareTeamDoctors on
CareTeams.CareTeamID = CareTeamDoctors.CareTeamID
inner join dbo.DoctorTbl as Doctors on
CareTeamDoctors.DoctorID=CareTeamDoctors.DoctorID
where CareTeamDoctors.CareTeamID = @careteamid
and CareTeamDoctors.DoctorID = Doctors.DoctorID
for xml auto, root('thedata')
```

sproc 2:

```
ALTER PROC [ex1].[xml_sp2]
@careteamid int
as 
declare @x xml

exec @x = ex1.xml_sp1
          @careteamid = @careteamid

select @x as XMLData
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to do is retrieve and store the xml data from sproc 1 in to @x in sproc 2.

You could achieve it very easily using [`OUTPUT` parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [xml_sp1]
   @careteamid INT,
   @xml_output XML OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SET @xml_output = (SELECT * FROM ... FOR XML AUTO, root('thedata'));
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [xml_sp2]
   @careteamid INT
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @x XML;

   EXEC [xml_sp1]
     @careteamid,
     @x OUTPUT;

   SELECT @x AS XMLData;
END;
GO
```

And final call:

```
EXEC [xml_sp2] @careteamid = 1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/XLJGI98069)**</kbd>

Consider using `BEGIN/END` block and end each statement with `;` to avoid possible nasty problems.

The full list of possible sharing data methods **[How to Share Data between Stored Procedures by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)**

Answer (score 3):

For the return value (i.e. `EXEC @ReturnValue = StoredProcName...;`), `INT` is the only datatype allowed. If this needs to really stay as a Stored Procedure then you can either use an `OUTPUT` variable or create a temp table or table variable in the second Stored Procedure and do `INSERT INTO ... EXEC StoredProc1;`.

However, given that the first Stored Procedure is only doing a simple SELECT statement, you would be far better off converting this to be an Inline Table-Valued Function (iTVF) as follows:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetData (@CareTeamID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

SELECT tab.col AS [CareData]
FROM (    
    SELECT CareTeams.CareTeamID, Doctors.DoctorID, Doctors.DoctorName,
           CareTeamDoctors.DateJoined, CareTeamDoctors.CurrentMember
    FROM   dbo.CareTeamTbl as CareTeams
    INNER JOIN dbo.CareTeamDoctorTbl as CareTeamDoctors
            ON  CareTeams.CareTeamID = CareTeamDoctors.CareTeamID
    INNER JOIN dbo.DoctorTbl as Doctors
            ON CareTeamDoctors.DoctorID=CareTeamDoctors.DoctorID
    WHERE  CareTeamDoctors.CareTeamID = @CareTeamID
    AND    CareTeamDoctors.DoctorID = Doctors.DoctorID
    FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('thedata'), TYPE -- "TYPE" causes result to be XML and not NVARCHAR
     ) tab(col);
```

Then just change the second stored procedure to be:

```sql
SELECT  care.CareData AS [XMLData]
FROM    dbo.GetData(@CareTeamID);
```

Or, if you actually need to make use of that XML data in the second Stored Procedure, do the following:

```sql
DECLARE @TempData XML;

SELECT  @TempData = care.CareData
FROM    dbo.GetData(@CareTeamID);
```

Finally, if you need the XML data to actually be of the XML datatype coming out of that iTVF (or even if you keep it as a Stored Procedure), then you need to add the `TYPE` option to the `FOR XML` clause, else what is returned is a string / `NVARCHAR(MAX)`:

```sql
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT ('thedata'), TYPE
```

Comment: I needed to pass it as xml datatype because my assignment requires me to use xquery to shred the xml data in to a temporary table, but I didn't mention that as I know how to do that pretty simply, the problem I was having was actually passing the first sproc's output to the second sproc to do this, hope this clarifies :)

Comment: @ConorS I get that. And as long as you are putting the value into an `XML` variable, then it is really all the same at that point. I was just showing how to do this if you or anyone was doing this for a job and not an assignment (i.e. properly and efficiently) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not try this instead of assigning output of sp1 directly

```
 declare  @t table
    (
    val xml
    )

    insert into  @t
    exec ex1.xml_sp1
    @careteamid = @careteamid

    select * from @t
```

Comment: This has some limitations that you should be aware: [INSERT-EXEC](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC)

Comment: Thank you for the link ,that was helpfull

Answer (score -1):

Will this work?

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = (select *
            from tableABC
            for xml auto, elements)
```

And then pass that variable to another sproc?

I go the answer from here

[How to insert FOR AUTO XML result into table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749948/how-to-insert-for-auto-xml-result-into-table).

Seems to me the idea is similar, or should work similar.